# Angular SSR + webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, deployment, angular-universal

I'm working on an angular projet,

versions:

-Angular CLI: 8.3.29
-Node: 12.14.1
-Angular: 8.2.14

I need to apply side rendering on it, I used the following command to set up angular univeral on my project

```
npm install @nguniversal/express-engine --save
```

After solving lot of problems (building, flickering, double loading page...) I now can launch it on my local environment with

```
build:ssr && serve:ssr
```

But when i try do deploy it on a production server, after building the project on the production server when I try to start the server with `node /dist/server/main.js`

I got the following error

> Error: Cannot find module 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'

I searched on forums and I found that I've to build my server side code with webpack

so I update my package.json to

```
"dev:ssr": "ng run my-app-name:serve-ssr",
"serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run my-app-name:server:production",
"build-wp:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
"webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
```

**webpack.server.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts'
  },
  externals: {
    './dist/server/main': 'require("./server/main")'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    noParse: /polyfills-.*\.js/,
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

**server.ts**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';


  const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));
  //server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

**angular.json**

```
{
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "my-app-name": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "projectType": "application",
          "prefix": "app",
          "schematics": {
            "@schematics/angular:component": {
              "styleext": "scss"
            }
          },
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/browser",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                "assets": [
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/assets"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/assets/sass/main.scss",
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
                ],
                "scripts": []
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                  ],
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true
                }
              }
            },
            "serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "my-app-name:build",
                "sslKey": "ssl/server.key",
                "sslCert": "ssl/server.crt"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "my-app-name:build:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "server": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/server",
                "main": "server.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "outputHashing": "media",
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                  ],
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "optimization": {
                    "scripts": false,
                    "styles": true
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "serve-ssr": {
              "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "my-app-name:build",
                "serverTarget": "my-app-name:server"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "my-app-name:build:production",
                  "serverTarget": "my-app-name:server:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "prerender": {
              "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "my-app-name:build:production",
                "serverTarget": "my-app-name:server:production",
                "routes": [
                  "/"
                ]
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {}
              }
            }
          }
        },
      },
      "defaultProject": "my-app-name"
    }
```

Now when i play the command

```
webpack:server
```

I got tons of error like this one :

> ERROR in ./src/app/components/auth/login/login.component.ts Module not
> found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'src/app/web-services/facebook-sdk.service' in
> 'C:\Code\my-app-name\src\app\components\auth\login'  @
> ./src/app/components/auth/login/login.component.ts 21:0-79 140:8-26  @
> ./src/app/components/auth/login/login.module.ts  @
> ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts  @
> ./src/app/app.server.module.ts  @ ./src/main.server.ts  @ ./server.ts

I don't know how to find where is the problems, is it a path which is have a bad value somewhere in my config ?

I checked for hours but i cant find the error.

please help me !!!!

Thank u in advance

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

In my components and in my modules I used imports with the relative paths

```
import { ApiClientService } from 'src/app/web-services/api-client.service';
```

I changed it to absolute paths

```
import { ApiClientService } from '../../web-services/api-client.service';
```

Build is Ok now